# Is the range and damage of all melee weapons the same in Team Fortress 2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

It seems that most weapons have the similar ranges and damage spreads.  Are a majority of these weapons exactly the same, or are each classes default melee and upgrades totally different?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Info From [Wiki](http://tf2wiki.net/wiki/Weapons).

Hope this helps

```
             Melee Weapons  
Name                              Damage    
                         Point Blank    Critical  

Bat                      24-46,          105  
Sandman                  24-46,          105  
(Baseball)               15,              45  
Shovel                   43-87,          195  
Equalizer                   See Note Below   
Fire axe                 43-87,          195  
Axtinguisher             23-43,          195  
Homewrecker              42-55,          146  
Bottle                   43-87,          195  
Pain train               59-72,          195  
Eyelander                43-87,          195  
Scotsman's skullcutter   78,             234  
Fists                    43-87,          195  
K.G.B.                   43-87,          195   
Wrench                   43-87,          195  
Bonesaw                  43-87,          195  
Übersaw                  43-87,          195  
Kukri                    43-87,          195  
Tribalman's shiv         38-47,          127  
Knife                    28-54,          120
```

Note on Equalizer:
The damage done scales inversely with health. Approximately `113.7 − 0.405x`, where `x is the amount of health the player currently has`, with a minimum of 33 when the player is at or above 200 health, and a maximum of 113 (before random damage and Critical hits). It should also be noted the Equalizer is the weakest melee weapon when Soldier has max health, and the strongest next to Spy's Backstab when Soldier is low.

For the Range of the weapons, I couldn't find weapon-specific range, the same Wiki states:

> The Eyelander's melee range is approximately 37% more than the Bottle and other melee weapons. The same is true for the Scotsman's skullcutter.

Comment: Wish my HTML table would work :(

Comment: Is there any information on the range of each of these weapons?

Comment: updated with a blurb on range

Comment: AFAIK The Eyelander and the Scotsman's SkullCutter are the only melee weapons with different ranges, every other weapon is the same range :)

Comment: Also, it would be great if we could find the damage scale for the equalizer.

Comment: Added Equalizer Formula

Comment: @Josh K: Use of the <pre> tag provide mono-spaced fonts for tables. Fixed.

Comment: All melee weapons have the same range except for the Eyelander, Skullcutter, and Eylander reskins (Headtaker and Nine Iron), which are increased by 37%.