# Which melee weapons have the longest and shortest attack range?

Tags: team-fortress-2

While it's easy to find damage data for melee weapons in TF2 ([this question for example)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/2979/3128), it's difficult to find the range of melee weapons.  The eyelander is described as being longer than the demoman's other weapons, but what is the actual range of various weapons.

Does anyone know the reach of the various melee weapons in TF2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order of range:

Disciplinary Action > Eyelander, HHH, Cladhaemaeh Moh, Scotsman's Skullcutter > All other Melee weapons

From the wiki for the Discliplinary Action:

> Despite not being listed in the description, this weapon has a 70%
>   longer range than most melee weapons, slightly more so than the
>   Eyelander

Answer (score 4):

I'm making some guesses here, but...

Eyelander, Unusual Horseless Headless Horsemann's Headtaker, and Scotsman's Skullcutter: 8 feet.
All other melee: 5 feet.

The real differences between melee weapons are the advantages and disadvantages listed for each one.

The other major difference is that the Scout's melee weapons always fire twice as fast for half the base damage.

Comment: this answer could use updating. All the new Demo swords / axes / golfclubs also have the increased range, as does the Soldier's Riding crop.

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, all melee weapons have the same range.  The Eyelander, as far as I know, is the only exception, and it has a greater range.  By what percentage, I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: The two Axes also share the Eyelander's increased range. Range isn't the primary differentiator between weapons, *firing rate* is.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: and special effects.  <3 Axtinguisher, Equalizer, and Your Eternal Reward.